# Accessing GDB through Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Can anyone tell me if there is  any way to access a standard GNU Debugger programatically through C++?

Comment: Have you already downloaded Eclipse CDT for C++ and tried using it? What problems exactly are you facing?

Comment: Programatically through C++: `system("gdb");`? How does eclipse come into this?

Comment: @RedX:I have already downloaded Eclipse CDT. My requirement is to access the GDB object from other process programmatically (Purpose is to simulate based on the APIs called)

Comment: @Mankarse: Programatically means i have to update the GUI based on the debugged values. It is a kind of simulator.

Comment: Search for the MI interface to GBD that should help you in your research.

Comment: @RedX: Thanks for the info. I'll search and let you know the results

Answer (score 1):

> Programatically means i have to update the GUI based on the debugged values.

It *sounds* as if you want to update Eclipse GUI depending on what GDB observes in the inferior (being debugged) process.

That is *exactly* what CDT itself does.

If that is in fact your question (which is exceedingly unclear), then `MI` interface is likely not the right answer. The right answer would be: look in CDT source and extend/modify it as appropriate. (FWIW, CDT itself uses MI interface to talk to GDB).

Comment: It is not to Update Eclipse GUI, based on the debugged values and the APIs i have to update my own GUI which is a standalone application not part of Eclipse CDT. How to achieve this?

Comment: Your question makes even less sense after this comment. I suggest you *think* about what you are actually trying to achieve, and then *describe* it in terms that don't require mind reading or magic crystall ball.

Comment: My requirement is there will be a C code developed in Eclipse CDT, while debugging this C code i have to access the debugger and to update my own GUI application(Simulator) which is developed in QT and C++

Answer (score 0):

Starting from GDB 7.1, Python scripts are supported with in GDB. It could be a option to look at http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/PythonGdb